# cannot click on docusign document

Tags: java, selenium, docusignapi

I need help. I am trying to automate a form using selenium ( Java ) which has been built in salesforce and the docusign has embedded into it. whenever i try to click a button on the docusign page i get the error : unable to locate the element or no such element found.. i have tried everything by using all types of wait commands ( waituntil element visible/ clickable etc., ) but still no luck can you please advise is there a way to click on the embed docusign page ? Appreciate your help!!

I am new to this forum please accept my apologies if i put anything wrong.. Thanks

Comment: please provide HTML code of that element

Comment: Hi Murali, thanks for your reply. Please find below code as requested.    <input track="disclosure-accepted-checkbox" id="disclosureAccepted" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" data-checked="disclosureAccepted" data-qa="disclosureAccepted">

Answer (score 1):

Just to be sure, check if the docusign is in the same frame. I have tested in salesforce before and we used to have iframes. Then you need to tell selenium to switch frames in order to find the elements.

If that is the case, use:

```
driver.switchTo().frame()
```

Comment: Thanks Anand, I will give a try and let you know. :)

Comment: Hi Anand, I have tried using the Iframe but no luck any other ideas ? I have tried with the ID, Index, etc, but throwing error as NO SUCH FRAME

Comment: Thanks Anand, the problem was solved by finding the iFrame by xpath

driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
driver.switchTo().frame( driver.findElement( By.xpath( iframeXpath ) ) );
and then return to the top window:

 driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

Answer (score 0):

This is how i have solved my problem.

driver.switchTo().frame( driver.findElement( By.xpath( iframeXpath ) ) );

and then return to the top window: driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

Thanks